# Reading Firebase data, onDataChange is never called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new here, currently I'm doing app that is working on background and checking processes in phone, if `"com.igg.castleclash"` is in processes List it set castleclash value to true and saving data in Firebase. Everything works fine, but I can't read the data from Firebase using `addValueEventListener`.

[image: **Firebase data img**]

```
public class SensorService extends Service {
    boolean castleclash = false;
    DatabaseReference databaaseUsers;


    public SensorService(Context applicationContext) {
        super();
    }

    public SensorService() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        startTimer();

            databaaseUsers.child("user1").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                UsersData user = dataSnapshot.getValue(UsersData.class);
                Log.i("user name", user.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w("Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
            Intent broadcastIntent = new
                    Intent("uk.ac.shef.oak.ActivityRecognition.RestartSensor");
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);


    }
    public void startTimer() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (true) {

                try {
                    wait(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                databaaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                final List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();

                for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process : runningProcesses) {
                    if (process.processName.equals("com.igg.castleclash")) {
                        castleclash = true;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        castleclash = false;

                    }
                }

                UsersData user1 = new UsersData(castleclash, "name");
                databaaseUsers.child("user1").setValue(user1);

            }

        }

    }



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems.  The most significant is that this processing is *not* occurring "in the background" as you think.  It is running on the main thread.  This is a common misunderstanding with Services as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

> **What is a Service?**
>
> Most confusion about the Service class actually revolves around what
>   it is *not*:
>
> - A Service is not a separate process. The Service object itself does not imply it is running in its own process; unless otherwise
>     specified, it runs in the same process as the application it is part
>     of.
> - A Service is not a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors).

An [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) is a convenient Service subclass for doing work off the main thread.

The `while(true)` loop in `startTimer()` runs endlessly. The call to `addValueEventListener()` in `onStartCommend()` is never executed because `startTimer()` never returns.

Database change listeners run on the main thread.  Because the main thread is blocked by the call to `wait()`, the `onDataChange()` callback would not be able to run (if the listener were successfully added).

Also, to see if your write to the database in `startTimer()` is failing, add a `CompletionListener`.  The most common reason for failure is permission denied caused by incorrect security rules.

```
UsersData user1 = new UsersData(castleclash, "name");
databaaseUsers.child("user1").setValue(user1, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        if (databaseError == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: success");
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: failed", databaseError.toException());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How is this helping me? If I can save data to Firebase, I should also be able to read the data, don't you think? As I said, everything is working perefctly fine, but reading the data is a problem.

Comment: You did well to post compilable code.  But it's not an [mcve], at least one that demonstrates the problem you're reporting.  When I run your code, it doesn't "work perfectly". it crashes because it's blocking the main thread.

Comment: while (true) made all the problems, I placed my while (true) loop in    
        `new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(true)
    {
       Thread.sleep(60000) 
       //REST OF CODE HERE//
    }

                    }
}).start();`, and now everything work alright. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you check out this video from David East?
 https://youtu.be/lpFDFK44pX8
I follow his method and it helps a lot.

The first line, you should write it like this,

> DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference

Then, you gonna need to declare another DatabaseReference for each db in console.

> DatabaseReference moooww = dbRef.child("nameOfYourDbValue");

The rest shown in the video.