# Firebase in Android, Storage is working but Database isn't

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to store an image with some relevant data regarding that image in Firebase. When I press the save button, the image is saved into my storage folder no problem, but the Database attributes just aren't being saved and I can't figure out why. 
This is my code:

```
String Storage_Path = "All_Book_Images";

String Database_Path = "All_Books";

Uri FilePathUri;

StorageReference storageReference;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;

int Image_Request_Code = 71;

ProgressDialog progressDialog;

Button imageButton, saveButton;
EditText title, author, price, category, additionalInfo;

ImageView SelectImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bookupload);

    SelectImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.book_image);

    title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    author = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.author_text);
    price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.price_text);
    category = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.category_text);
    additionalInfo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.info_text);

    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Database_Path);
}

public void imageButton(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Image"),0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        FilePathUri = data.getData();

        try{
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePathUri);
            SelectImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getActualImage(Uri uri){
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return  mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
}

public void uploadData(View view){

    if(FilePathUri != null){


        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference reference = storageReference.child(Storage_Path + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getActualImage(FilePathUri));


        reference.putFile(FilePathUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {



                String Title = title.getText().toString();
                String Author = author.getText().toString();
                String Price = price.getText().toString();
                String Category = category.getText().toString();
                String AdditionalInfo = additionalInfo.getText().toString();

                Book book = new Book(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString(), Title, Author, Price, Category, AdditionalInfo);

                String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();

                databaseReference.child(id).setValue(book);

                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double totalProgress = (100*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded % " + (int)totalProgress);
                    }
                });


    } else {
        // show message
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please select data first",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

What's causing this to interact with the Storage aspect of Firebase fine, but not the Database?

Comment: Add a [CompletionListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener) to `setValue(book)`.  Maybe a problem with your security rules.  See the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44742421/4815718) for an example.

Comment: did you tried for example seting a value with only the title or author ? like .setValue(Title); and see if that works in first place?, also, to upload this kind of things you should consider using a hashMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my code was actually working OK, I just had the rules of my Firebase Database set up incorrectly. The code I posted in the question should work for anyone trying to implement this.

Comment: Can you tell me how you resolved it I have tried my every inch.

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet from Firebase Official Doc, i have writen some of your requirement inside, but you get the idea

```
private void writeNewPost(String Title, String Price, String Author) {

    String key = databaseReference.push().getKey();
    Post post = new Post(Title, Price, Author);
    Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> books = new HashMap<>();
    books.put(Title, postValues);
    books.put(Price, postValues);
    books.put(Author, postValues);

    mDatabase.child(key).updateChildren(books);
}
```

for more info : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

PS: you can use `updateChildren()` or `setValue()` , it depends which one you need.

If you use `setValue()` in this way, the data is overwritten at the specified location, including the secondary nodes.

You can make simultaneous updates to multiple locations in the JSON tree with a single call to `updateChildren()`.